Do we need a plagiarism-checker tag?
There are a number of threads here containing "plagiarism checker". The combination of the plagiarism and the software tags goes in the right direction, but both tags are a bit broader...
Does it make sense to introduce a tag plagiarism-checker for questions about, well, plagiarism checkers?

There is also a higher number of threads containing "Turnitin", but not necessarily "plagiarism checker".

Looks like there is a consensus here, so I have created the tag and marked this as status-complete. Thanks for the suggestion!

i have retagged some of the older questions that fit into the category and have written a short explanation of what the tag is supposed to be about, feel free to add.
